# Dart RegEx : How to get the positions of all matched groups

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

When executing a RegExp, dart correctly matches the groups and returns the `Match` strings. However, dart does not return the start and end index positions of all the groups.

Example: the following code correctly captures two groups.

1. Email  Id: example@domain.com
2. example@domain.com

Dart returns the same start and end index in both the cases. Start index = 5 and end index = 35.

However for the second group I expected start index to be 16 and end index to be 34.

```
void main() {
  
const String EMAIL = r'email\s+id\s*:\s*(.+?)(?:\s|$)';
const String sampleString = "     Email  Id: example@domain.com                 This is a very long useless string that follows the email                                                                                ";

 print(firstMatches(sampleString,EMAIL));
  
}

Map<String, int> firstMatches(
  String txt,
  String pattern,
) {
  Map<String, int> groups = {};
  RegExp regExp =
      RegExp(pattern, caseSensitive: false, multiLine: false);
  RegExpMatch? match = regExp.firstMatch(txt);
  if (match != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < match.groupCount + 1; i++) {
      groups.addAll(
          {match.group(i) != null ? match.group(i)!.trim() : "": match.start});
    }
  }
  return groups;
}
```

Inspecting `RegExpMatch? match` under debug console shows a private member _match which does hold the indexes of all the captured groups.

[image: captured groups]

For a project I need to parse large text files and I have several RegEx patterns with multiple matches per line. Is there anyway I could get the start and end indexes from all groups?

Comment: 1. You use a non-capturing group (`(?:)`), so you really have only one group. 2. `start` and `end` are properties of the `RegExpMatch`, not of a group.  They identify where in the input string the *entire regular expression* was matched.  If you must know the indices where your groups start and end, one way would be to match the entire regular expression first and then separately parse the components from that.

Comment: Either re-parse the matches, or somehow access the private `_match` property, but that might turn out much messier than a mere reparsing.